# Adding Pallets to Substrate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, substrate, polkadot

This is a very basic question, but I am following the ["nicks" tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/add-a-pallet/#add-the-nicks-pallet-to-the-node-template) from the Substrate network, and it's not very clear how - after I have added the pallet - I install or "pull in" these dependencies so I can inspect the code. I was expecting something like node_modules folder where everything is put once you run `npm i`, but that is a different environment. I have run `cargo build` but to no avail. Please advise.

Comment: The cargo stuff goes into `~/.cargo`, not the current directory.

Comment: @forgetso The tutorial shows that crates appear under the pallets/ directory of the project.

Comment: I can't find that part of the tutorial but you can view the source of all the pallets [on github](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame).

Comment: @forgetso Thank you, but that is replying in a different question altogether. I am saying that when I add a crate as a dependency I don’t see the code being downloaded and added to the project.

Answer (score 1):

When you add dependency in `Cargo.toml`, by default, the actual dependency will download and store on global Cargo registry `$HOME/.cargo/` and specify the version in `Cargo.lock` inside project directory, not the actual dependency.

For a tutorial on Substrate, after adding Nick's pallet and running cargo build, you can check the code of downloaded pallet_nick in `$HOME/.cargo/`. The easiest way is to download `rust_analyzer` plugin to your VSCode and `CRTL + Click` to the dependency name inside Cargo.toml, it will take you to the library.

Comment: And what is in the “pallets” folder then?